# getting an error message in Github "Sorry, a file exists where you’re trying to create a subdirectory. Choose a new path and try again"

Tags: git, github, repository, commit, git-commit

Why is this statement "Sorry, a file exists where you’re trying to create a subdirectory. Choose a new path and try again" arising when I try to make commits in my repo, does anyone facing the same problem? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Given that you're using the GitHub web interface here, this isn't really a *Git* question. However, you would have the same problem in Git, on your local computer: suppose you have a file named `path/to/file.ext` on your local computer. You now ask your computer to create a file named `path/to/file.ext/another.ext`. What does your local computer say about this? (The exact error will depends on whether you're using Windows, macOS, Linux, etc., but all of them reject it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this error when trying to create a folder with the same name of a file existing on the branch.

So, look for a file and rename it or simply change the name of the folder you' re trying to create.

Deleting a file is also a simple process.